# Lyapunov Function showing a unstable critical point of system of ODE to be stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I am considering the following system of ODE:

$$x'=y, y'=x-x^3$$

where (0,0) is a critical point of it.

By considering its locally linear system, I found that this critical point is an unstable saddle point. And I believe that this conclusion is true since I had verified it by plotting the phase portrait.

However, when I consider the following Lyapunov Function,
$$V(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(u^2-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}v^2$$
upon computation, the derivative of V by the system is constant zero, so it is negative semidefinite.
Would this fact show that (0,0) is a stable critical point?

Thank you very much for reading the post.

Comment: How are $u$ and $v$ connected with $x$ and $y$?

Comment: As far as I remember, any Lyapunov function must be zero only at zero. In your case, $V$ is zero in two isolated points, and it does not have a minimum at 0. How exactly do you apply the Lyapunov theorems?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that solutions of the ODE follow the level curves of $V$, the point $(0,0)$ is also a saddle point of
$$
V=\frac12y^2+\frac14-\frac12x^2+\frac14x^4,
$$
thus your claim is wrong/not applicable.